# Нужна помощь по Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux

Вот есть допустим начальный state

```js
const initialState = [
       'Test1',
       'test2'
    ];
```

все это дело идет сюда

```js
const todo = (state = initialState, action) => {
  if(action.type === 'ADD_TODO'){
    return [
      ...state,
      action.todo
    ]
  }
  return state;
}
```

Подскажите а вот например я данные получаю с сервера через fetch

и закину эти данные в

> const initialState

так и нужно делать ? или как то по другому ?

Что посоветуете ? Я просто только учусь.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать `redux-thunk` и в отдельном `action` выполнять `fetch` запрос и только после получения данных с сервера передавать их в `store`.
Получится что-то типа:

```
const fetchInitState = () => dispatch => {
  let promise = fetch(url[, options])
  .then(res => dispatch(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Этот `action` вызывается в `componentDidMount()` нужного элемента. Как правило это `App.js`.